# Extract text from a reference file in h5py

Tags: python, reference, h5py

I have downloaded an .h5 file which has various objects (most of them of the format `data.dat`) including one named `History.txt`. Upon accessing it, it shows `<HDF5 dataset "History.txt": shape (), type "|O">`. I am not able to access the text inside this object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225532/in-h5py-what-is-type-o) it says that `type "|O"` is a reference file. Converting it to `np.array` is showing an output in which all the lines and text are squashed together. Is there a way to extract/read the text which is there in this object?

The code is as follows:

```
data_0180 = h5py.File('file.h5', 'r+')
data_0180['OutermostExtraction.dir'].keys()
```

Output of this has many keys, I've written the first few:

```
<KeysViewHDF5 ['History.txt', 'Y_l2_m-1.dat', 'Y_l2_m-2.dat', 'Y_l2_m0.dat']>
```

These .dat keys contain data, while this `History.txt` contains some kind of information about the file and that data. I want to read that information. When I try to print it:

```
print(data_0180['OutermostExtraction.dir/History.txt'])
```

it shows the following output:

```
<HDF5 dataset "History.txt": shape (), type "|O">
```

Converting it to np.array shows the following output (I have mentioned only the first couple of lines, the output is large)

```
array('WaveformModes_4872 = scri.SpEC.read_from_h5("SimulationAnnex/Catalog/NonSpinningSurrogate/
BBH_CFMS_d18_q1_sA_0_0_0_sB_0_0_0/Lev4/rhOverM_Asymptotic_GeometricUnits.h5/Extrapolated_N2.dir", 
**{})\n# # WaveformBase.ensure_validity(WaveformModes_4872, alter=True, assertions=True)\n# WaveformModes.ensure_validity(WaveformModes_4872, alter=True,
assertions=True)\n# hostname = kingcrab\n# 
cwd = /mnt/raid-project/nr/woodford\n# datetime = 2017-01-16T19:24:54.304846\n# scri.__version__ = 2016.10.10.devc5096f2\n# spherical_functions.__version__ = 2016.08.30.dev77191149\n',
      dtype=object)
```

with the shape of the array as `()`. How do I extract/read the text in this object?

Comment: datatype "|O"> is use for objects: these can be object references, region references, arrays or lists. Please share your code so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: @kcw78 I have added the code.

Comment: That's interesting....I have never seen `shape ()`...I thought that meant it was empty/null. I'm not sure what to make of it. How do you convert it to an array? I'm guessing `np.array(data_0180['OutermostExtraction.dir/History.txt'])` ? What is the output if you print the shape of that array? Can you share the output when you print this dataset?

Comment: @kcw78 I have added the np.array output as well as the shape

Comment: Ahhh...I forgot h5py stores variable length strings as a object dtype -- "|O". That's what you have. To complicate matters, the array is a scalar array, so typical numpy indexing doesn't work. See answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments, you have a variable length string. NumPy doesn't have a dtype to support this data type, so h5py stores with an object dtype (along with some metadata). Adding to the "fun", the array is a scalar array, so you can't access elements with typical NumPy indexing. This is where `.item()` comes to the rescue. Add `.decode()` to finish the process. Your code should look something like this:

```
data_str = np.array(data_0180['OutermostExtraction.dir/History.txt']).item().decode('utf-8')
```

To demonstrate the behavior (start to finish), I wrote an example starting from the variable length string example in the h5py documentation. First it creates a file ('foo.hdf5') with a dataset of variable length string data -- I used the first 3 lines from your output.

After writing, the file is closed and reopened in read-only mode. The dataset is read into an array (`arr`), then `.item()` is used to access the element and `.decode('utf-8')` to decode it (assumes it was encoded as `'utf-8'`). The last line shows how to pull all these methods together in a single Python statement that returns a decoded string (variable `data_str`). Once you have the string, you can parse it as needed.

**Example Below:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

vlstr = 'WaveformModes_4872 = scri.SpEC.read_from_h5("SimulationAnnex/Catalog/NonSpinningSurrogate/' + \
        'BBH_CFMS_d18_q1_sA_0_0_0_sB_0_0_0/Lev4/rhOverM_Asymptotic_GeometricUnits.h5/Extrapolated_N2.dir",' + \
        '**{})\n# # WaveformBase.ensure_validity(WaveformModes_4872, alter=True, assertions=True)\n# WaveformModes.ensure_validity(WaveformModes_4872, alter=True,'

dt = h5py.string_dtype(encoding='utf-8')

with h5py.File('foo.hdf5','w') as h5f:        
    ds = h5f.create_dataset('VLDS', dtype=dt, data=vlstr)   
          
with h5py.File('foo.hdf5','r') as h5f:            
    ds = h5f['VLDS']
    print('dtype=',ds.dtype)
    print('string dtype=',h5py.check_string_dtype(ds.dtype))
    
    arr = np.array(ds)
    print('\n',arr.item().decode('utf-8'))
    
    data_str = np.array(h5f['VLDS']).item().decode('utf-8')
    print('\n',data_str)
```